# My Next.js application is not acknowledging changes and not refreshing when I edit my files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I start my project, and so far so good.

```
npm run start                                        

> mk-market@0.1.0 start
> next start

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from /Users/...../market/.env.local
warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (appDir) in next.config.js.
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.

info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback
```

But after this no more console output, not when making requests and not saving changes in my files, it will, however, output server side `console.logs()`.

The page works in my browser (at `localhost:3000`). But when I save changes (let's say add a `<h1>Hello</h1>`) I don't get auto re-compilation. And `npm run start` doesn't make any changes either. The only way to get my newly saved changes is to run  `npm run build` followed by `npm run start`

This has happened to me in the past, the only way for me to get it working again was to start a completely new project. But I have gotten a little too far for that now.

I've googled like crazy, but the only thing I could find being somewhat closely related was about capital letters in the naming of my pages in my app folder, but that's not the case here.

Also, I just created a brand new project with `npm create-next-app`, but the same thing is happening. When running `npm run start` I get:

```
Error: Could not find a production build in the '/Users/erikingman/MK/mk-test/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id
    at NextNodeServer.getBuildId (/Users/erikingman/MK/mk-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:352:23)
    at new Server (/Users/erikingman/MK/mk-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:146:29)
    at new NextNodeServer (/Users/erikingman/MK/mk-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:166:9)
    at NextServer.createServer (/Users/erikingman/MK/mk-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:167:24)
    at async /Users/erikingman/MK/mk-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:187:31
    at async NextServer.prepare (/Users/erikingman/MK/mk-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:149:24)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (/Users/erikingman/MK/mk-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/render-server.js:109:17) {
    type: 'Error'
}
```

I have to run `npm run build` before I can run it, I have no recollection of doing that for new projects in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the correct command for development mode. It's `npm run dev` and not `npm run start`. The start is for deployment, which works after a `npm run build`.

That's what you should see in your `package.json`, in the `scripts` part:

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start",
  "lint": "next lint"
},
```

Comment: Ohmy, so I used the right command for about a month, and all of a sudden managed to screw it up. Don't know how!.. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: this does not solve the issue, on prod we are running npm start adter build, now once you add data. this not reflecting on prod, don't tell me each time we make changes we need to make build.

Comment: @Amitkumar you are talking about the caching behavior of Next.js on production, which is a different story. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76204353/data-is-not-being-updated-always-getting-the-same-result-after-the-project-is.